# How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript, variables, properties, object-literal

Why does the following work?

```
<something>.stop().animate(
    { 'top' : 10 }, 10
);
```

Whereas this doesn't work:

```
var thetop = 'top';
<something>.stop().animate(
    { thetop : 10 }, 10
);
```

To make it even clearer: At the moment I'm not able to pass a CSS property to the animate function as a variable.

Comment: see also: [create object using variables for property name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3153969/1048572)

Comment: see also: [creating object with dynamic keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19837916/1048572)

Comment: see also: [add dynamically named properties to object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/1048572)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Answer (score 905, accepted):

`{ thetop : 10 }` is a valid object literal.  The code will create an object with a property named `thetop` that has a value of 10.  Both the following are the same:

```
obj = { thetop : 10 };
obj = { "thetop" : 10 };
```

In ES5 and earlier, you cannot use a variable as a property name inside an object literal.  Your only option is to do the following:

```
var thetop = "top";

// create the object literal
var aniArgs = {};

// Assign the variable property name with a value of 10
aniArgs[thetop] = 10; 

// Pass the resulting object to the animate method
<something>.stop().animate(
    aniArgs, 10  
);
```

ES6 [defines](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) *ComputedPropertyName* as part of the grammar for object literals, which allows you to write the code like this:

```
var thetop = "top",
    obj = { [thetop]: 10 };

console.log(obj.top); // -> 10
```

You can use this new syntax in the latest versions of each mainstream browser.

Comment: I understand! Thank you!
Shoudln't this also work with eval?
I mean it doesn't work in my example at the moment, but I thin it should... :-)

Comment: @Marcel: `eval()` wouldn't work inside an object literal for dynamic property names, you'd just get an error.  Not only that, but `eval()` really shouldn't be used for such things.  There's an excellent article on correct and incorrect usage of `eval`: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx

Comment: @AndyE consider updating "recent versions" and "current IE TP" with some more specific time like "Versions later than XXX" or "after 2014-mm" (I'd make change myself, but I don't know what good values would be.

Comment: for ES6, is there a way to leave out the property if the key is null/undefined? For example, in `{[key] : "value"}`, if key was null, it would give `{ null: "value"}`, whereas I'd like the result to be `{}`

Answer (score 206):

With [ECMAScript 2015](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) you are now able to do it directly in object declaration with the brackets notation:

```
var obj = {
  [key]: value
}
```

Where `key` can be any sort of expression (e.g. a variable) returning a value.

So here your code would look like:

```
<something>.stop().animate({
  [thetop]: 10
}, 10)
```

Where `thetop` will be evaluated before being used as key.

Answer (score 20):

**ES5 quote that says it should not work**

Note: rules have changed for ES6: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274327/895245

Spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

> PropertyName :
>
> - IdentifierName
> - StringLiteral
> - NumericLiteral
>
> [...]
>
> The production PropertyName : IdentifierName is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the String value containing the same sequence of characters as the IdentifierName.
>
> The production PropertyName : StringLiteral is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the SV [String value] of the StringLiteral.
>
> The production PropertyName : NumericLiteral is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let nbr be the result of forming the value of the NumericLiteral.
> 2. Return ToString(nbr).

This means that:

- `{ theTop : 10 }` is the exact same as `{ 'theTop' : 10 }`

  The `PropertyName` `theTop` is an `IdentifierName`, so it gets converted to the `'theTop'` string value, which is the string value of `'theTop'`.
- It is not possible to write object initializers (literals) with variable keys.

  The only three options are `IdentifierName` (expands to string literal), `StringLiteral`, and `NumericLiteral` (also expands to a string).

Comment: Downvoters: I was the *first* to quote any standard on this question. The ES6 quote on the top answer was edited *after* I answered, and that standard was not yet accepted at the time. If you happen to know why else I'm getting downvotes, please explain, I just want to learn. I might as well get the peer pressure badge...

Comment: I guess the downvote was mostly because your answer doesn't offer a solution, and is "not useful" in that regard. Voting towards peer pressure :-)

Comment: @Bergi thanks for having the courage! :-) But I think I have answered the question *directly*: Q: "Why does the following work?". A: because ES5 says so. "What to do about it?" is implicit. Did you downvote the top question for saying "It is impossible" *without a standard quote* before someone edited in the ES6 solution?

Comment: Ah, right. I typically cite the specific questions in a blockquote to make it clear when I answer them directly. Quoting the standard can make a good answer even better, but currently your post doesn't even answer the question imo. Stating what can make a key in ES5 doesn't imply *how* they work. Surely `thetop` is an `IdentifierName`, so *why does it not work*? That question is still open.

Comment: @Bergi thanks again for explaining to me! I have updated it to make it more explicit. I hadn't done it before because I though it was obvious, because we can write `{a:1}.a`, so `a` clearly not expand the variable value in the identifier case. But yes, explaining further is an improvement in this case.

Answer (score 14):

**ES6 / 2020**

If you're trying to push data to an object using "key:value" from any other source, you can use something like this:

```js
let obj = {}
let key = "foo"
let value = "bar"

obj[`${key}`] = value

// A `console.log(obj)` would return:
// {foo: "bar}

// A `typeof obj` would return:
// "object"
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: ```obj[`some-prefix-${key}`] = value``` also works if someone wish to enjoy the flexibility to modify the key variable. The result is `{ some-prefix-foo: "bar" }`

Answer (score 6):

I have used the following to add a property with a "dynamic" name to an object:

```
var key = 'top';
$('#myElement').animate(
   (function(o) { o[key]=10; return o;})({left: 20, width: 100}),
   10
);
```

`key` is the name of the new property.

The object of properties passed to `animate` will be `{left: 20, width: 100, top: 10}`

This is just using the required `[]` notation as recommended by the other answers, but with fewer lines of code!

Answer (score 6):

Adding square bracket around the variable works good for me. Try this

```
var thetop = 'top';
<something>.stop().animate(
    { [thetop] : 10 }, 10
);
```

Comment: This won't work in older versions of EcmaScript, but nowadays this is a very clean approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try like this:

```js
const arr = [{
    "description": "THURSDAY",
    "count": "1",
    "date": "2019-12-05"
},
{
    "description": "WEDNESDAY",
    "count": "0",
    "date": "2019-12-04"
}]
const res = arr.map(value => {
    return { [value.description]: { count: value.count, date: value.date } }
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a **simple example** about the differences between ES6 and ES5, so I made one. Both code samples create exactly the same object. But the ES5 example also works in older browsers (like IE11), wheres the ES6 example doesn't.

**ES6**

```
var matrix = {};
var a = 'one';
var b = 'two';
var c = 'three';
var d = 'four';

matrix[a] = {[b]: {[c]: d}};
```

**ES5**

```
var matrix = {};
var a = 'one';
var b = 'two';
var c = 'three';
var d = 'four';

function addObj(obj, key, value) {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

matrix[a] = addObj({}, b, addObj({}, c, d));
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: As a commenter pointed out, any version of JavaScript that supports arrow functions will *also* support `({[myKey]:myValue})`, so this answer has **no actual use-case** (and, in fact, it might break in some bizarre corner-cases).

Don't use the below-listed method.

---

I *can't believe* this hasn't been posted yet: just use arrow functions with anonymous evaluation!

*Completely* non-invasive, doesn't mess with the namespace, and it takes just one line:

```
myNewObj = ((k,v)=>{o={};o[k]=v;return o;})(myKey,myValue);
```

demo:

```js
var myKey="valueof_myKey";
var myValue="valueof_myValue";
var myNewObj = ((k,v)=>{o={};o[k]=v;return o;})(myKey,myValue);
console.log(myNewObj);
```

<s>useful in environments that don't support the new `{[myKey]: myValue}` syntax yet, such as—apparently; I just verified it on my Web Developer Console—Firefox 72.0.1, released 2020-01-08.</s> *I stand corrected; just wrap the thing in parenthesis and it works.*

(I'm sure you could potentially make some more powerful/extensible solutions or whatever involving clever use of `reduce`, but at that point you'd probably be better served by just breaking out the Object-creation into its own function instead of compulsively jamming it all inline)

---

not that it matters since OP asked this ten years ago, but for completeness' sake and to demonstrate how it is **exactly** *the* answer to the question as stated, I'll show this in the original context:

```
var thetop = 'top';
<something>.stop().animate(
    ((k,v)=>{o={};o[k]=v;return o;})(thetop,10), 10
);
```

Comment: Arrow functions and computed property names were introduced at the same time. Your console check is incorrect, as you need to type `({ [myKey]: myValue })` into the console to make it an object, [not a _block_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3731802/4642212). _“It takes just one line”_ — Sure, the entire minified jQuery library takes just one line. _“non-invasive”_ — not true if the object has getters, setters, or is a Proxy target.

Comment: The answer can be rewritten as var myNewObj = (function (myKey, myValue) { o = {}; o[myKey] = myValue; return o; })(myKey, myValue); for support versions < ES6

Answer (score 2):

Given code:

```
var thetop = 'top';
<something>.stop().animate(
    { thetop : 10 }, 10
);
```

Translation:

```
var thetop = 'top';
var config = { thetop : 10 }; // config.thetop = 10
<something>.stop().animate(config, 10);
```

As you can see, the `{ thetop : 10 }` declaration doesn't make use of the variable `thetop`. Instead it creates an object with a key named `thetop`. If you want the key to be the value of the variable `thetop`, then you will have to use square brackets around `thetop`:

```
var thetop = 'top';
var config = { [thetop] : 10 }; // config.top = 10
<something>.stop().animate(config, 10);
```

The square bracket syntax has been introduced with ES6. In earlier versions of JavaScript, you would have to do the following:

```
var thetop = 'top';
var config = (
  obj = {},
  obj['' + thetop] = 10,
  obj
); // config.top = 10
<something>.stop().animate(config, 10);
```

Comment: `obj['' + thetop]` can just be replaced by `obj[thetop]`. It’s automatically stringified, unless it’s a symbol.

Answer (score 2):

2020 update/example...

A more complex example, using brackets and literals...something you may have to do for example with vue/axios. Wrap the literal in the brackets, so

> [ ` ... ` ]

```
{
    [`filter[${query.key}]`]: query.value,  // 'filter[foo]' : 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ES5 implementation to assign keys is below:

```
var obj = Object.create(null),
    objArgs = (
      (objArgs = {}),
      (objArgs.someKey = {
        value: 'someValue'
      }), objArgs);

Object.defineProperties(obj, objArgs);
```

I've attached a snippet I used to convert to bare object.

```js
var obj = {
  'key1': 'value1',
  'key2': 'value2',
  'key3': [
    'value3',
    'value4',
  ],
  'key4': {
    'key5': 'value5'
  }
}

var bareObj = function(obj) {

  var objArgs,
    bareObj = Object.create(null);

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(function([key, value]) {

    var objArgs = (
      (objArgs = {}),
      (objArgs[key] = {
        value: value
      }), objArgs);

    Object.defineProperties(bareObj, objArgs);

  });

  return {
    input: obj,
    output: bareObj
  };

}(obj);

if (!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function(obj){
    var arr = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
      arr.push([key, obj[key]]);
    });
    return arr;
  }
}

console(bareObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want object key to be same as variable name, there's a short hand in ES 2015.
[New notations in ECMAScript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```
var thetop = 10;
var obj = { thetop };
console.log(obj.thetop); // print 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
var thetop = 'top';
<something>.stop().animate(
    new function() {this[thetop] = 10;}, 10
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This way also you can achieve desired output

```js
var jsonobj={};
var count=0;
$(document).on('click','#btnadd', function() {
    jsonobj[count]=new Array({ "1"  : $("#txtone").val()},{ "2"  : $("#txttwo").val()});
    count++;
    console.clear();
    console.log(jsonobj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>value 1</span><input id="txtone" type="text"/>
<span>value 2</span><input id="txttwo" type="text"/>
<button id="btnadd">Add</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following for ES5:

```
var theTop = 'top'
<something>.stop().animate(
  JSON.parse('{"' + theTop + '":' + JSON.stringify(10) + '}'), 10
)
```

Or extract to a function:

```
function newObj (key, value) {
  return JSON.parse('{"' + key + '":' + JSON.stringify(value) + '}')
}

var theTop = 'top'
<something>.stop().animate(
  newObj(theTop, 10), 10
)
```