# Turning .innerHTML or .value into a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to turn the .innerHTML or .value part of document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML into a variable.

```
<script language="javascript">
function changeTheText(){
    var newValue = "innerHTML";
    document.getElementById( "myJavaTest" ).newValue = "world";
    alert( newValue );
}
</script>
<span onclick="changeTheText()" id="myJavaTest">Hellow</span>
```

It isn't throwing an error, but it is also not working.  The alert is popping fine.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: Your `.newValue` thing would be indistinguishable from the literal property called "newValue", so that syntax could never work. (Which is what it's doing BTW: creating a new property on your element called "newValue" with the value "world")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the square brackets, which can be used to access objects properties.

```
document.getElementById( "myJavaTest" )[newValue] = "world";
```

Have a look at this question, it might help :

[JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 4):

Square brackets instead of a dot.

```
document.getElementById( "myJavaTest" )[newValue] = "world";
```