# How to set key from variable in jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change the "nom_articole" key to the ***s*** value?

```
        var s = document.getElementById("myvalue").textContent;

        var obj = {
            url: "http://localhost:53698/mobile_ODataService.svc/",
            jsonp: true,
            errorHandler: function (error) {
                alert(error.message);
            },
            entities: {
                nom_articole/*I want here the s value in nom_articole place*/: { key: "id" },
            }
        };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable as identifier in an object literal. You just can add another dynamic property after object creation:

```
var s = document.getElementById("myvalue").textContent;

var obj = {
  url: "http://localhost:53698/mobile_ODataService.svc/",
  jsonp: true,
  errorHandler: function (error) {
     alert(error.message);
  },
  entities : {}
};
obj.entities[s] = { key: "id" };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this after the object creation.

```
var s = document.getElementById("myvalue").textContent;

var obj = {
    url: "http://localhost:53698/mobile_ODataService.svc/",
    jsonp: true,
    errorHandler: function (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
};
obj[s] = {
    nom_articole: { key: "id" },
};
```