# Creating dynamic scope variables

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create dynamic scope variable.

Here is the json object:

```
{
"status": true,
"res": {
    "call": [
        {
            "percent": 100,
            "name": "150+"
        }
    ],
    "stores": [
        {
            "percent": 100,
            "name": "150+"
        }
    ],
    "web": [
        {
            "percent": 21,
            "name": "120-150"
        },
        {
            "percent": 79,            
            "name": "150+"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the code what i am trying to do:

```
for(keys in jsonObject.res){
    $scope.<SomeString+keys> = 'something';
}
```

Please suggest me what would be the better way to achieve this?

Assume jsonObject is the object what i have specified above

Comment: Something like this $scope['SomeString' + keys] = 'something';

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

[$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) Converts Angular expression into a function with .

```
for(key in jsonObject.res){
    $parse('someObj.key').assign($scope, 'somevalue')
    $scope.apply()
}
```