# How do I get get the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my a snippet code from my nodeJs progam here. I have a map called transMap. I would like to read the value for yy, get "ipaddress" and pass it out as json along with its value. I would have expected json response to be `{ "ipaddress" : "http://derivedURL.com"}`. But what I get is `{ arg : "http://derivedURL.com"}`

I am missing something really basic here.

```
var transMap = new Map();
        transMap.set('xx', {rPath:'/xxs', sn:2,res:['rid']});
        transMap.set('yy', {rPath:'/yys', sn:3, res: ['ipaddress','dns']});
        transMap.set('zz', {rPath:'/zzs', sn:4, res:['uri', 'fqdn']});

       var arg = (transMap.get(yy)).res[0] ; //arg = ipaddress
       var jsonResponse = { arg : "http://derivedURL.com"}; 
       console.log(jsonResponse); //
```

Edit1: arg has to get the value of "ipaddress" obtained from transMap. Derived URL is derived from a different function thats immaterial to this discussion.

My console now reads:  `{ arg : "http://derivedURL.com"}`. But I want it to read `{ "ipaddress" : "http://derivedURL.com"}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do :

```
var jsonResponse = {
  arg : 'someArg'
}
```

`arg` does not get evaluated to it's value. Instead it gets used as 'arg' itself. To have it evaluated to it's value, you can set it like this:

```
jsonResponse[arg] = 'someArg'
```

When you use the `[]` notation, the key (here: `arg`) always gets evaluated in scope.

[**Example jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dMZx5/)

Comment: This answer doesnt help me or I am not understanding it. Please see my edit to the question                                              Edit1: arg has to get the value of "ipaddress". Derived URL is derived from a different function thats immaterial to this discussion.

My console now reads:  { arg : "http://derivedURL.com"}. But I want it to read { "ipaddress" : "http://derivedURL.com"}

Comment: Instead of `var jsonResponse = { arg : "http://derivedURL.com"};`, do `var jsonResponse[arg] = "http://derivedURL.com";`.