# Why doesn't HTML inserted with JS respond to clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See this [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0482j9vs4e). I have a list of things to bring to college. I have a text input with an add button. When you type something into the input and click add, it gets added. However, when I click the close button of the item that got added, it doesn't work. The `alert('test')` also doesn't show up, so I guess that the new close icon isn't responding to clicks. How can I get it to work? Here's my code:

**Javascript**

```
  $("#packing_list_css .close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').hide();
    alert('test');
  });
  $("#everyday_ul button").click(function() {
    new_item = $("#everyday_ul :text").val();
    new_item.trim();
    if (new_item.length != 0)
      $("<li><span class=\"close\">&times;</span>" + new_item + "</li>").insertBefore( "#everyday_ul :text" );
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Everyday</p>
<ul id="everyday_ul">
  <% everyday.each do |item| %>
    <li><span class="close">&times;</span> <%= item %></li>
  <% end %>
  <input type="text"><button class="btn btn-link">Add</button>
```

Comment: paste the html code too, screenshot doesn't help a lot...

Comment: and [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you:

1. Get all the elements that match `#packing_list_css .close` in the document
2. Bind an event handler to each of them
3. Add a new element that matches that selector

The new element didn't exist for steps 1 and 2 so it never gets an event handler bound to it.

Bind the event handler to `#packing_list_css`, let the click event bubble up to it, and check to see what was actually clicked.

```
$("#packing_list_css").on("click", ".close", function() {
```