# Create object array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have inherited a project and need to recreate an object in this format (dynamically) but have not sure how to do it. This is what I tried and it's almost there:

```
//this creates [{ "Country": ["Canada", "United States of America"] }]
filters = [];
var object = {};
object.Country = [];
object.Country.push('Canada', 'United States of America');
filters.push(object);
//alert(JSON.stringify(filters));
console.log(JSON.stringify(filters));

//currently getting this
//filters = [{ "Country": ["Canada", "United States of America"] }]

//need this
//filters = { 'Country': ['Canada', 'United States of America'] };
```

I have a form where the user will select the column in a table (Country) and then enter one or more countries.  Currently the filter works based on the hard coded object above.  I need to now change the object on the fly for other columns.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(filters[0]));`

Comment: The above response is perfect, you have an array of objects...you can access it using just the array index :)

Comment: In your desired format, `filters` is a single object, not an array. It's the same as `object`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking; but change filters = []; to filters = {};

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar You can't use `push` on that.

Comment: You get what you want if you work with `object`, not `filters`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I did not understand what he wanted.

Comment: adeneo this works console.log(JSON.stringify(filters[0]));  can i add another object so it looks like this (post an answer and I will give you the credit): filters = {'Country': ['Canada', 'United States of America'],
            'Element': ['Page1_A0']
        };

Comment: Yes you can. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/218196