# How can I set the value of and index parameter within a .forEach loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had the following suggestion on how to set the value of a field dynamically:

[Can I set the value of a property dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299789/can-i-set-the-value-of-a-property-dynamically#24299954)

```
var data = {roles: "Admin:Xxxx:Data"};
var user = {data: {role:{}}};

data.roles.split(':').forEach(function(v) {
  user.data.role['is' + v] = true; 
})
```

This works very well for me.

Now I need to set the value of another parameter based on the presence or absence of different roles. 
The formula is

```
index = 0 if the Test role is present
index = index + 1 if the Xxxx role is present
index = index + 2 if the Yyyy role is present
index = index + 100 if the Data role is present
```

I would appreciate some advice on how I could combine this into the solution that I have. If possible I would like to make the solution so that it could extended with more roles later on. I would like to have to avoid writing multiple if statements if possible.

Comment: Use a for loop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an object.

```
var indexes = {'Xxxx':0,'Yyyy':index+1,'Data':index+100};

index=indexes['Xxxx'];
```