# Get key and values in an object and out put it to be used as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I'm using filterify (http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/) plugin to filter some divs. Now what i'm trying to do is get the data attributes from `a` element and match it with the target div element.

When I enter the values manually it works fine, example, `ft.trigger({ type : ["red"] }` but when i'm trying to make it dynamic and mix it with variables that's where it fails.

My script look something like this:

```
$(function(){ 


    var ft = $.filtrify("boxes");


    $("#filter_nav a").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        // coding the values manually works
        // ft.trigger({ type : ["red"] }


        var customData = $(this).data()

        for (var key in customData) {

            ft.trigger({ key : [customData[key]] });
            // should return something like ft.trigger({ type : ["red"] });

        }

    });


});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="filter_nav">
    <li><a href="#" data-type='red' >Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-type='yellow' >Yellow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-type='blue' >Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-type='green' >Green</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" data-progress='20' >20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-progress='40' >40</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-progress='60' >60</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-progress='80' >80</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="boxes">

    <div data-type='red' data-progress='20' class="box red"></div>
    <div data-type='yellow' data-progress='40' class="box yellow"></div>
    <div data-type='blue' data-progress='60' class="box blue"></div>
    <div data-type='red' data-progress='20' class="box red"></div>
    <div data-type='green' data-progress='80' class="box green"></div>
    <div data-type='yellow' data-progress='40' class="box yellow"></div>
    <div data-type='blue' data-progress='60' class="box blue"></div>
    <div data-type='red' data-progress='20' class="box red"></div>


</div>
```

I'm suspecting that my setup here is wrong

```
ft.trigger({ key : [customData[key]] });
```

more about trigger method:
http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/trigger.html

Can you help me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the trigger method is a json like the following (the one you mention that manually works):

```
{ type : ["red"] }
```

You want to create that json from the data attributes. The json will have a property with name `type`, the name of the property coming from the data attribute name and the value `["red"]` would be an array with a single element coming from the data attribute value.

You were getting the value right, but the property name of the json would always be `key` instead of `type` or `progress`.
You can pass the arguments to trigger in the following way:

```
for (var key in customData) {
    var triggerOptions = {};
    triggerOptions[key] = [customData[key]];            
    ft.trigger(triggerOptions);        
}
```

Basically, you have to create the object first and then create the new properties in the object using the [square bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

well you say that you expect something like...

```
should return something like ft.trigger({ type : ["red"] });
```

but your code returns

```
ft.trigger({ key : ["red"] })
```

maybe your key has the wrong name