# Getting a request value for a dynamically generated key

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I need to get a value from the request in Parse.com's javascript cloud code, for a param that I'm fetching dynamically.

It goes like this. I'm getting a list of key objects from the datastore, and for each one I get the actual key:

```
var key = keyObject.get("Key");
console.log("key = " + key);
```

The key here is printed correctly. For example it can be `IsActionMovie`.

Now I need to see if a value for this key exists in my request.

```
var valueFromRequestForKey = request.params.key;
console.log("valueFromRequestForKey = " + valueFromRequestForKey);
```

The printout here is always `undefined`.

Needless to say this works:

```
var valueFromRequestForKey = request.params.IsActionMovie;
```

So how do I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let´s say the var `key` has the value `IsActionMovie` as in your example. With `request.params.key` you are trying to access a property named `key` in the params object. (This won´t try to evaluate the key object and access a property by that name)

What you want is to access a property named `IsActionMovie` in the params object, while writing code that can access any poperty whose name is set in the `key` var. You can use the [square bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object) for that:

```
var valueFromRequestForKey = request.params[key];
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkttdv96/).