# How to access property names that contain numbers within a loop?

Tags: javascript, properties

I want to access values of below elments

```
opener.document.EditView.flight_no1_c.value
opener.document.EditView.flight_no2_c.value
opener.document.EditView.flight_no3_c.value
opener.document.EditView.flight_no4_c.value
```

Here only numbers are changing ranging from 1 to 4.
How can I make this into loop.

Comment: 1. `for` 2. You access object's properties with `[]` operator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop and call properly using `[]` insteand on `.`, see below code

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++ ){
  opener.document.EditView["flight_no"+i+"_c"].value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
for(var key in opener.document.EditView){
    if(key.match(/^flight_no\d+_c/)){
       console.log(key.value);
    }
}
```