# Google Sites Listitem

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am working with the google sites list item.

The classes are [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/list-item#getValueByName(String)) and [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/column#getName())

I have been able to iterate through the columns and put all of the column headers in to one array with the following code.

```
//Global
 var page = getPageByUrl(enter URL here)
 var name = page.getName();
 function getInfo() {
 var columns = page.getColumns();
   //Get Column Names
 for (var j in columns) {
    var cName =columns[j].getName();
    columnList.push(cName);
  }
}
```

Now I want to be able to get each row of the listitem and put it in its own array.

I can add the variable

```
function getInfo() {
 var columns = page.getColumns();
 var listItems = page.getListItems();//new variable
   //Get Column Names
 for (var j in columns) {
    var cName =columns[j].getName();
    columnList.push(cName);
  }
}
```

Now that I have the variable the output is [ListItem, ListItem, ListItem, ListItem]
So I can use a .length and get a return of 4. 
So now I know I have 4 rows of data so based on my wants I need 4 arrays.

Small interjection here, Not a coder by trade but code as a precursor to wants becoming needs.

A buddy of mine who is a JS coder by trade showed me this code which does work. With the logger added by me.

```
for (var i in listItems) { 
  if (listItems.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      item = listItems[i];
        for (var x = 0; x < columnList.length; x++) {
          attrib = item.getValueByName(columnList[x]);
          Logger.log("Logging value of get list page get value by name = " + columnList[x] + " " + attrib);
      }
     }
     }
```

Which brings the total code to

```
var name = page.getName();
var listItems = page.getListItems();
var listCount = listItems.length
var listList = [];
var columns = page.getColumns();
var name = columns[0].getName();
var item, attrib = 0;
var columnList = [];
Logger.log(listItems);
Logger.log(name + " was last updated " + page.getLastUpdated());
Logger.log(name + " was last edited " + page.getLastEdited());
var listCount = 0;

//Get Column Names
  for (var j in columns) {
      var cName =columns[j].getName();
      columnList.push(cName);
  }
  Logger.log(columnList);
   // Get index of Due Date   
  var dueDateValue = columnList.indexOf("Due Date");
  Logger.log("The index of due date is " + dueDateValue);

for (var i in listItems) { 
if (listItems.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    item = listItems[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < columnList.length; x++) {
        attrib = item.getValueByName(columnList[x]);
        Logger.log("Logging value of get list page get value by name = " + columnList[x] + " " + attrib);
      }
     }
     }



}`
```

Forgive the above code as it has been a bit of a sketch pad trying to work this out.
I am a bit behind on understanding what is happening here

```
for (var i in items) { // This is for each item in the items array
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
```

if items is an array, how can we use has own property? Doesn't that belong to an object? Does an array become an object?

My questions are two category fold.

Category # 1
What is happening with the hasOwnProperty?
-Does the array become an object and thus can be passed to .hasOwnProperty value

Category # 2
Is this the only way to take the values from the listitem and populate an array
- If it is, is there some way to delimit so I can pass each row into it's own array
- If it isn't , why does it work with the hasOwnProperty and why doesn't it work without it in the example below

```
for (var i in listItems) {
    for (var y = 0; y < columnList.length; y++) {
     item = listItems[i];
     listList = item.getValueByName(columnList[x]);
     Logger.log("Logging my version of list naming " + listList);
      }
```

In which I get a "Invalid argument: name (line 41"  response. Highlighting the

```
listList = item.getValueByName(columnList[x]);
```

Not looking for a handout but I am looking to understand the hasOwnPropertyValue further.

My current understanding is that hasOwnValue has to do with prototyping ( vague understanding ) which doesn't seem to be the case in this instance
and it has to depend on a object which I described by confusion earlier.

To clarify my want:
I would like to have each row of listitems in its own array so I can compare an index value and sort by date as my current column headers are

```
["Project", "Start Date" , "End Date"]
```

Any and all help is much appreciated for this JS beginner of 2 weeks.

Comment: I think you should first compact your question. Trust me, no one's gonna read all of that

Comment: i think the entire thought process should be included to understand the evolution of the problem. The ultimate desire of of the outcome and the major obstacle in the way.

Comment: Why hasownproperty  is used when going over an array using for in or data objects with itetterable non data prototype members is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848

Comment: Thanks HMR. I'll look over that. Initially is it comparing array indexes and returning matching results?

Comment: Yes but there is no guarantee of the order when using for in loops. Didn't see your reply, on SO when replying to someone you can use the at sign @ followed by the user name so they'll get a notice. Commenting on questions or answers will notify the person who posted the question or answer so no @ is needed unless you comment on a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can be inside of an object as the value of a member:

```
 {"myFirstArray":"[one,two,blue]"}
```

The above object has one member, a name/value pair, where the value of the member is an array.

Here is a link to a website that explains JSON.

[Link To JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)
[JSON explained by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)
There are websites that will test the validity of an object:

[Link to JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

An array has elements, and elements in an array can be other arrays.  So, there can be arrays inside of arrays.

`.hasOwnProperty` returns either `true` or `false`.

[Documentation hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Interestingly, I can use the `hasOwnProperty` method in Apps Script on an array, without an error being produced:

```
function testHasProp() {
  var anArrayTest = [];
  anArrayTest = ['one', 'two', 'blue'];
  Logger.log(anArrayTest);

  var whatIsTheResult = anArrayTest.hasOwnProperty('one');
  Logger.log(whatIsTheResult);

  Logger.log(anArrayTest);
}
```

The result will always be false.  Using the `hasOwnProperty` method on an array doesn't change the array to an object, and it's an incorrect way of using Javascript which is returning false.

You could put your list values an object instead of an array.  An advantage to an object is being able to reference a value by it's property name regardless of where the property is indexed.  With an array, you need to know what the index number is to retrieve a specific element.

Here is a post that deals with adding properties to an object in JavaScript:

[StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

You can either use dot notation:

```
objName.newProperty = 'newvalue';
```

or brackets

```
objName["newProperty"] = 'newvalue';
```

To add a new name/value pair (property) to an object.

Comment: Thank you @Sandy Good, I will gladly return and upvote when I am able to do so.  This is extremely helpful.