# Create dynamic name for object properties

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function renderCategoryList (receivedCategories) {
        var allCategories = [];
        for (var i in receivedCategories) {
            var category = {}
            category.categoryName = receivedCategories[i].Name;
            category.categoryId = receivedCategories[i].Id;
            category.categoryParentCategoryId = receivedCategories[i].ParentCategoryId;
            if (receivedCategories[i].ParentCategoryId != null) {
                var parentLevel = 0;
                var parentId = receivedCategories[i].ParentCategoryId;
                for (var z = 0; receivedCategories.length > z; z++) {
                    var parentName = "parentName" + parentLevel;
                    if (receivedCategories[z].Id == parentId) {
                        category.parentName = receivedCategories[z].Name; // the "category.parentName" should be dynamic. At first run this should be category.parentName0. 
                        parentId = receivedCategories[z].ParentCategoryId
                        var parentExists = true;
                        parentLevel++; //if a parentId exists this should raise the level with +1 and therefore at the next run the name should be "category.parentName1". 
                        z = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            allCategories.push(category);
        }
        return allCategories;
}
```

I am trying to create a dynamic name for the variable `parentName` in `category`. At first run through the for loop the name of this variable should be `parentName0` - second run it should be `parentName1` and so on until the `receivedCategories[i].ParentCategoryId` is `null`.

The method shown above ignores the `var parentName = "parentName" + parentLevel;` and therefore in each run of the loop the `category.parentName` is overridden.

How can I make the `parentName` variable in `category` dynamic?
I hope I have explained this in an understandable way. Otherwise please let me know so I can try to elaborate.

Comment: Ok, this has nothing to do with c# or MVC, so ive removed thiose tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square bracket notation:

```
var parentLevel = 0;

function renderCategoryList (receivedCategories) {
    ...
    category["parentName" + parentLevel] = receivedCategories[z].Name;
    parentLevel++;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick! I will accept your answer when possible.