# How to use more parameters in an element.someEvent function

Tags: javascript, callback, onclick, dom-events

Well, I don't know any other way to ask this. So, Here is an example:

```
element.onclick = myfunction(50, 3);

function myfunction(event, offset, space){
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff here with offset & space
}
```

Now when I call this function it cannot recognize my "event" object because the other function parameters conflicts with it, I know that the function should be called as (callback) but I need the parameters to do somethings for me, So how to do this?

I need to use my function with more than one element, So each of them will get different (offset & space) value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll show where is your mistake. You're overridding `onclick` with this:

```
element.onclick = myfunction(50, 3);
```

This expression actually means that you call `myfunction`, then save the returned value into `element.onclick`. If you want to assign a function, you should write it as the following:

```
element.onclick = myfunction;
```

Now I'll list some of the ways to pass data to the event handler.

**Scope**

You can use JavaScript's scope feature:

```
var a = 50, b = 3;

element.onclick = function (e) {
  // use e(event), a, or b just normally
};
```

For example

```
(function () {
  var element, offset = 1, space = 2;

  element = document.getElementById('x');

  element.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log('onclick', offset, space);
  };

  // Modify the scope variables every second
  window.setInterval(function () { offset++; space++; }, 1000);
})();
```

**`bind()`**

If you want different `offset` and `space` values for different handlers within the same scope, you can [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) them:

```
element.onclick = function (o, s, evt) {
  // Note, `this` variable is a reference to `element`.
  console.log('onclick', o, s);
}.bind(element, offset, space);
```

Note, that the arguments are passed by value(i.e. their values will not be changed within the handler), unless they are objects. However, if you bind an object, the object will be still bound to the scope:

```
var nodeX, nodeY;

nodeX = document.getElementById('x');
nodeY = document.getElementById('y');

nodeX.onclick = function (y, evt) {
  console.log(y.id);
}.bind(nodeX, nodeY);

// Modify nodeY.id after 5 seconds
window.setInterval(function () { nodeY.id = 'modifiedY'; }, 5000);
```

The click handler will log `y`, if the user clicks on `nodeX` in the first 5 seconds. After the first 5 seconds `modifiedY` will be logged.

Of course, you can bind static values as well:

```
someFunction.bind(element, 1, 2);
```

**Custom properties**

You can also set the values as the `element` properties(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)):

```
element.myData = {offset: 50, space = 3};
```

then use within the callback:

```
element.onclick = function (e) {
  var target;

  if (!e) var e = window.event;

  target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // Use target.myData.offset, target.myData.space
};
```

Here we assign anonymous function as `element`'s [click event](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click) [handler](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes).

The event handler normally accepts an [event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event) argument. However, Microsoft defined its own rules, where the event argument is stored in `window.event`. So we assign `e` to `window.event`, if `e` is undefined.

If Microsoft had followed W3C standards, we would have used only `e.target` as the [event target](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget). But the company defined its own property called [`srcElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So we pick one of them by means of the [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR):

```
target = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

Since the [event target is a reference to the object that dispatched the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), then it becomes a reference to our `element` node. Consequently, we can get any `element` property including `myData`: `target.myData`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..
I need to use the same function with different element's onclick, but each element will get different (offset and space).

Comment: @HamedAdil, added another option to the answer. However, I'd recommend using the scope, if possible(and it's more often possible, than not).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However I didn't understand how this solution works.