# How to rename json key's value in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer, key

```
function replaceJsonStringify( key, value1 ) {

    var $edit = $("#trafficLog");
    var currentValue = $edit.val();
    var jsonConnect = { "time":getLongTime(), [key] : value };
    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonConnect);
    var newValue = jsonObj + "<br>" + currentValue;

    $edit.val(replaceBR(newValue));   }

replaceJsonStringify( "connectFlag", connect );
```

I want to rename the json key's value.

The above code works fine in Chrome, but it is not working in IE11, 10..

I want to know **how to rename the json key's value**.

The problem in the code is " [key] : value "

IE debugging : `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number.`

Please answer about this problem.

Comment: Share a working snippet using `<>` from the toolbar that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically create object keys in IE 11 (Expected identifier, string or number, not a comma issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392656/dynamically-create-object-keys-in-ie-11-expected-identifier-string-or-number)

Answer (score 0):

I guess IE can't understand yet computed properties in the object. Change this:

```
var jsonConnect = { "time":getLongTime(), [key] : value };
```

to this:

```
var jsonConnect = { time: getLongTime() }
jsonConnect[key] = value;
```

Comment: In Chrome, the result is {"time":"2018-3-8 20:15:37","connectFlag":"connect"} but In IE, an error still occurs. –

Comment: I am so sorry!! That was work well! Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't have support for computed property names. You need to replace this line:

```
var jsonConnect = { "time":getLongTime(), [key] : value };
```

with this:

```
var jsonConnect = { "time":getLongTime() };
jsonConnect[key] = value;
```

See [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility) for more details.

Comment: In Chrome, the result is 
{"time":"2018-3-8 20:15:37","connectFlag":"connect"}

but In IE, an error still occurs.

Comment: I am so sorry!! That was work well! Thank you very much