# Transforming arrays / objects: how can I create dynamically named objects within a for loop?

Tags: javascript

Trying to manipulate this:

```
input = [ 
[ ['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f'] ], 
[ ['g','h'], ['i','j'],  ]
]
```

to

```
output = [
    {a: 'b', c: 'd', e: 'f'},
    {g: 'h', i: 'j'},
]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
function transform(array) {
  result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){

    // How can I create an object here? 

    object.array[i][j][0] = array[i][j][1];
    }
  }
return result; 
}
```

I'm trying to solve this as a coding challenge so I don't necessarily want the answer but I'm unsure of how to proceed. Since the number of arrays that have a pair of strings inside is not uniform (for instance, first set of arrays within the input array has 3 sets, and the second set has 2 sets, I reckon I need to dynamically create objects within each loop that I can add to the results array at the end. How can I do this?

I don't think I'm supposed to use any sort of fancier / higher order functions. The goal is to build up my familiarity with the fundamentals.

Comment: `var obj = {}; for (...) { obj[key] = value; }`. See [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1184123/218196)

Comment: I’d recommend you work on a function that just does one transformation so the nested loops don’t get in the way of understanding. Write one that just transforms `[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]` to `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name might help.

Comment: @FelixKling How does that solve the issue since I need to be able to create these objects x amount of times and x is varied?

Comment: The whole point of a loop is to write code once and have it be executed x times. Not sure where the confusion is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *reduce* to process the outer and inner arrays, e.g.

```js
var input = [
             [['a','b'], ['c','d'],['e','f'] ],
             [['g','h'], ['i','j'],]
            ];

// For each outer array
var result = input.reduce(function(acc, a){

  // Create an object from the inner arrays
  acc.push(a.reduce(function(acc, a) {
    acc[a[0]] = a[1];
    return acc;
  },{}));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log('With reduce\n');
console.log(result);

// Same algorithm using for loops:
var result2 = [];

// For each outer array
for (var i=0, iLen=input.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  var acc = {};
  var a = input[i];

  // Loop over the inner arrays to build an object, 
  // then push into result array
  for (var j=0, jLen=a.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    var b = a[j]
    acc[b[0]] = b[1];
  }
  result2.push(acc);
}
console.log('\nWith loops')
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without reduce?

Comment: @FaiqueMoqeet—yes, just replace it with a *for* loop. It's actually not much more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Input.reduce((memo,num) => {
    memo[num[0]]=num[1];
    return memo;
},{})
```

Comment: Code only answers are not that useful. Please *explain* your solution so that others can learn. I'm sure the OP doesn't know what `reduce` is.

Comment: This answer has the same issue as Ling Qing Meng's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `for..of` loops to iterate each inner array, create object, set property to element at index 0, value to element at index 1, push object to array at completion of nested `for..of` loop

```js
let input = [
  [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd'],
    ['e', 'f']
  ],
  [
    ['g', 'h'],
    ['i', 'j']
  ]
];

let output = [];

for (let arr of input) {
  let o = {};
  for (let [key, value] of arr) {
    o[key] = value;
  }
  output.push(o);
}

console.log(output);
```