# How to convert array string to json object?

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have to convert `project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date]` to `project.maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date`.

The problem is, i m getting `project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date]` through api in a variable and it can be anything like `project[blablabla]`. So i want to apply global solution for all types of values like this.

I have this:

```
var json = {
    'key': 'project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date]',
    'value': '2017-02-22'
};
```

Now what i need to do is call the API and send data as

`var project = {};
 project['maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date'] = '2017-02-22'`;

I tried `JSON.parse` but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me out here. I m new to this.

Thanks

Comment: the first doesn't look like valid anything ... and what you want doesn't look useful (what value should it be?) ... and, as shown, this has absolutely nothing to do with JSON

Comment: I want to post project.maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date as JSON key in api. I m getting project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date] from another API.

Comment: you still have only described about 10% of your problem

Comment: can you post the result of `JSON.stringify(project)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: @Rajesh it's not duplicate. Please check my updated explanation in the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX, I have added more explanation in the question. Please check it.

Comment: none of the code you've posted is valid javascript - so, it's hard to understand the data you want to "convert"

Comment: @RavinderSingh first its still unclear. Try giving sample. Secondly it still looks like adding dynamic property to object

Comment: @JaromandaX I added more explaination with example in question. Please check it.

Comment: the issue is that string `project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date]` is a string, and it's not an array, at all, in no sense of the word array with respect to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic way would be

```
var json = {
    'key': 'project[maximum_contract_amount_estimated_completion_date]',
    'value': '2017-02-22'
};
var a = json.key.match(/^(.*)\[(.*)\]/);
window[a[1]] = window[a[1]] || {};
window[a[1]][a[2]] = json.value;
```