# Java Script how to add object to object

Tags: javascript

For example I have object:

```
var customLabel = {
    restaurant: {
        label: 'R'
    },
    bar: {
        label: 'B'
    }
};
```

And I have the value:

```
var val = "Big";
```

How can I add this value to `customLabel`?

The result must be such as  `Big: { label: 'Big' }` element.

Comment: Shouldn't the desired result be `big: {label: 'B'}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: It's very unclear what you want.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
customLabel.Big = new Object();
customLabel.Big.label = 'Big';
```