# Adding Auto Increment Number to the JSON Object in the For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I need to get the `var i` need to be appended to the left side of the object declaration. I am unable to find how to append that. Kindly help me to get rid of the Error.

If any Other Solution available also i will follow it up.

**I have tried the below code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text_count=5;
var textbox = new Object();
for (var i = 1; i<=text_count; i++)
    {
            textbox.meta_key_textbox='Meta Key';
            textbox.meta_key_value_textbox='Meta Value';
    };

    var textbox_string = JSON.stringify(textbox);
    alert(textbox_string);
</script>
```

I get the last Value alone in this. But I am unable to get all the Values that are in the Loop.

But when i do this method manually it works. Kindly Clarify on this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var text_count=5;
 var textbox = new Object();
   textbox.meta_key_textbox='Meta Key';
   textbox.meta_key_value_textbox='Meta Value';
   textbox.meta_key_textbox1='Meta Key One';
   textbox.meta_key_value_textbox1='Meta Value One';
   var textbox_string = JSON.stringify(textbox);
alert(textbox_string);
</script>
```

Comment: you mean just += instead of =?

Comment: No i need to append the `i` value as in my below example to the object through the loop

Comment: use template literals

Comment: oh sorry, just textbox['meta_key_textbox' + i]

Comment: Ya great bro i got it. Thanks @aw04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: np, please ignore all the answers btw, never seen so many terrible answers to a simple question lol

Answer (score -1):

you assign the same value in each iteration, use the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var text_count=5;
var textbox = new Object();
for (var i = 1; i<=text_count; i++)
    {
            var text = "meta_key_textbox" + i;
            var value_text = "meta_key_value_textbox" + i;
            textbox.text='Meta Key';
            textbox.value_text='Meta Value';
    };

    var textbox_string = JSON.stringify(textbox);
    alert(textbox_string);
</script>
```

Comment: Just by adding this itself i got it - `textbox['meta_key_textbox' + i]`. Thanls for your Effort

Answer (score -1):

```
var text_count=5;
var textbox = new Object();
var arrKey = [];
var arrValue = [];
var values = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

for (var i = 1; i<text_count; i++) {
  arrKey.push({key: "textbox.meta_key_textbox" + i, value: values[i-1]});
  arrValue.push({key: "textbox.meta_key_value_textbox" + i, value: values[i -1]});
}

textbox.meta_key_textbox='Meta Key';
textbox.meta_key_value_textbox='Meta Value';

for (var i = 1; i<text_count; i++)
{

        textbox[arrKey[i-1].key]= 'Meta Key ' + arrKey[i-1].value;
        textbox[arrValue[i-1].key]= 'Meta Value ' + arrValue[i-1].value;
};

var textbox_string = JSON.stringify(textbox);
alert(textbox_string);
```