# How to create an object with a key

Tags: javascript, json

I want to achieve this:
[image]

I've tried this:

```
        userId: {
          isAdmin: false,
        }
```

userId is a const where its value is like 447785 but the resulted object just show userId as a property not a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
{
    [userId]: {
        isAdmin: false
    }
}
```

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015 and here http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/#computed-property-keys

Answer (score 2):

```
var users = {}
users[userId] = {isAdmin: false}
```

Feels like this is probably a dupe of a Q on SO that explains it properly. I'll have a look...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object