# How to create number object property name dynamically using javascript with integer key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to generate a object with number object property using javascript new Object().

For example I want to create a object dynamically by the below format
{1:"1",2:"2",3:"5"}

I tried below

```
var json_str=new Object();  
$([1,2,3]).each(function(i,t){
        var str="'json_str."+t+"="+t+"'";
        eval(str);
});
```

But it is not created object like that, if it is string value it will create.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and map the objects.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(k => ({ [k]: k.toString() })));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Values should be strings

Comment: @JustinNiessner JavaScript keys are always strings. It's not possible to have an integer key

Comment: @mhodges I know. Which is why the now-deleted answer that says this isn't possible was the one I up-voted first. But it technically was wrong since you can also use `Symbol`s as keys.

Comment: @JustinNiessner True, you can use Symbols as keys as well, although they don't show up in `Object.keys()` or `for...in`, so they work differently than traditional string properties. But meh, semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Simple JS:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
let object = {};

for (let num of array) {
  object[num] = String(num);
}

console.log(object);
console.log(Object.keys(object)); // your keys will automatically become strings too
```

You should avoid using `eval()` where-ever possible to prevent accidental injection exploits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make this an Array, then you can
push objects onto it:

```
var json_str=new Array();  
$([1,2,3]).each(function(i,t){
   json_str.push( { [t] : t });
});

json_str: Array(3)
0:{1: 1}
1:{2: 2}
2:{3: 3}
```