# typescript add element to object

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to add `'Open Street Map': this.LAYER_OSM.layer,` in this object (att the end)? :

```
layersControl = {
  baseLayers: {
    'Route': this.LAYER_GStM.layer,
    'Satellite': this.LAYER_GSaM.layer,
    'Terrain': this.LAYER_GTM.layer
  }
};

this.layersControl.baseLayers ...add/push... ??
```

I try with:

```
this.layersControl.baseLayers['Open Street Map'] = this.LAYER_GTM.layer;
```

but I have this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ 'Route': TileLayer; 'Satellite': TileLayer; 'Terrain': TileLayer; }' has no index signature.
```

Comment: The same way you add all the other properties. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet, I want to add the 4th element dynamically with code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: @JBNizet, no same solution, I have a space in 'Open Street Map', is it a problem for me

Comment: That is not a problem at all. Read the answers carefully.

Comment: The problem you have is not related to adding a property. It's related to not giving a proper type to your object, or to not explicitly type it as `any`. Define it as `layersControl: any = { ...`, and the error should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution find by [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet):

```
layersControl: any = {
  baseLayers: {
    'Route': this.LAYER_GStM.layer,
    'Satellite': this.LAYER_GSaM.layer,
    'Terrain': this.LAYER_GTM.layer
  }
};

this.layersControl.baseLayers['Open Street Map'] = this.LAYER_OSM.layer;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to add the index signature:

```
 interface ILayersControl  {
  baseLayers: {
   [key: string]: TileLayer
  }
 }
```

So you can do

```
 const layersControl: ILayersControl = {
    baseLayers: {
      'Route': this.LAYER_GStM.layer,
      'Satellite': this.LAYER_GSaM.layer,
      'Terrain': this.LAYER_GTM.layer
    }
 };

 layersControl.baseLayers["Open Street Map"] = this.LAYER_OSM.layer;
```