# JavaScript Replace }, with ,"_deleted":true},

Tags: javascript, node.js

Input:

```
{"_id": "1235625485","_rev": "1-jsdjsid456862"},
```

Output:

```
{"_id": "1235625485","_rev": "1-jsdjsid456862","_deleted":true},
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is not a portal to get code for free. Its a portal where we help our fellow developers with their problems. This means you have to share your attempts and we will help you fix it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to replace, its just addition of property. maybe you were unable to put it correctly in words. below is example how to add property.

```
var a = {"_id": "1235625485","_rev": "1-jsdjsid456862"}
a._deleted = true;
console.log(a)
```

Comment: First, missing explanation. Second, you can look for *how to add key to an object* and mark post as duplicate

Comment: @Rajesh Fixed the explanation part, IMO OP was unable to put it in correct words