# Difference between the setState of static and dynamic Key and Value?

Tags: reactjs

When I used to `setState` the value for the User Name statically, I used to use the below code to set the value in the variable name.

```
this.setState({ 'userName' : event.target.value })
```

but the same when I used to set the same value in the same key name but this time dynamically.

In my HTML attribute I set the name as `userName` and `onChange` I call the function with the event. In that `event.target.name` I get the `userName` and `event.target.value` I get the value that I typed but during the `setState`, the below code did not work:

```
this.setState({ event.target.name : event.target.value })
```

Instead of that, I used to set the key by using `[event.targe.name]` that's working fine:

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value })
```

Actually what I need is, what is the difference between the above two codes and how does it work in statically and dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wy we need to put e.target.name in square brackets \[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376353/wy-we-need-to-put-e-target-name-in-square-brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a syntax error:

```
this.setState({ event.target.name : event.target.value })
```

The following means the *value of `event.target.name` will be the key name*:

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name] : event.target.value })
```

In other words:

- `{ name: value }` means `object.name = value`, which means **assign `value` to `"name"` key**.
- `{ [name]: value }` means `object[name] = value`, which means **assign `value` to the key with the value of `name`**.

Comment: Thanks Bro Really Useful.

Comment: Happy to help. Can you accept the answer if it answered your question?

Comment: your answer Accepted bro, Thanks for the kind response.