# Jquery: How to create a plain object with dynamic names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) that you can create an plain object like this:

```
var y = {
  name: "Pete",
  age: 15
};
```

However, I would like to add name and value dynamically to it, for example if we have something like:

```
<input type="text" name="$dynamicName" id="myinput">
```

That I can create an object like this:

```
var y = {
  name: "Pete",
  $('#myinput).attr('name'): $('#myinput).val(),
};
```

But this will throw an error:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

How can I use `$('#myinput).attr('name')` as a name of a plain object?

Comment: `y[$('#myinput).attr('name')] = $('#myinput).val();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using as an **Array**.

Like:

`y[$('#myinput').attr('name')] = $('#myinput').val();`

then you can access it as a simple object.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are wanting to do it will add the `age` item to the array and then set its value to whatever is in the textbox `onclick`.

```js
var y = {
  name: "Pete"  
 };
function go(){
 y[$('#myinput').attr("name")] = $('#myinput').val();
console.log(y)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"name="age" id="myinput">
<input type="button"  onclick="go(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var y = {name: "Pete"};
y[$('#myinput').attr('name')] = $('#myinput').val()];
```

You also have unclosed single quotes:

```
var y = {
    name: "Pete",
    $('#myinput').attr('name'): $('#myinput').val(),
};
```

Comment: You've removed the quotes (and thus broken it) rather than add the missing one (obviously a typo)

Comment: That I did, which was incredibly silly. Apologies and edited.
I'd still use the first approach personally though.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes were because the second option doesn't work, which was the whole point of the question.   First part should be ok though.