# Convert form data to JSON with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I convert some elements of my form to a JSON?

I want the JSON data not based on `"name": "value"`, but `"value1": "value2"`.

Where "value1" is the input element 1 and "value2" is the input element 2.

And what if I want to add an object to the previous JSON data? For example,

```
dataBefore = {"key": "1"}; 

dataAfter = {"key": "1", "data": "2"};
```

The code have i tried,

```
var person = {};
var key = $('#com-key2').val();
person[key] = $('#com-value2').val();
```

And the UI like this,
[form example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcteI.png)

Note: ID of all input element is same

How to do that? Sorry if the language is hard to understand

Comment: please share some code you have tried already.. or some more context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an answer to your question.

If there's wrong, please tell me.

```js
var obj = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value4"};
var index = 0;
for(var key in obj){
    $('.key').eq(index).val("new_"+key);
    $('.value').eq(index).val("new_"+obj[key]);
    index++;
}

$('.container').each(function(){
  var key = $(this).find('.key').first().val();
  var value = $(this).find('.value').first().val();
  obj[key] = value;
})

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<input class="key" name="key1"/>
<input class="value" name="value1"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
<input class="key" name="key2"/>
<input class="value" name="value2"/>
</div>
<div class="container">
<input class="key" name="key3"/>
<input class="value" name="value3"/>
</div>
```

Comment: if i keep using ID, can it still be?

Comment: I noticed that you said "ID of all input element is same". IDs should not be the same. "It must be unique in a document" by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: If I wanna parse the data and show it into the input's element again, should make looping or not?

Comment: I modified the answer for you. Just a simple usage without error handling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean for the first part, but to add an object:

`dataBefore = {"key": "1"};`

`dataBefore["data"] = "2"`

`dataBefore = {"key": "1", "data": "2"};`

Edit: This might be what you're looking for

```
var obj = {};
var key = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
var text = document.getElementById('myOtherInput').value;
obj[key] = text;
```

Comment: if i have many input form, do you have a code to loop over each element?

Answer (score 0):

First, you do NOT need jQuery for combining two objects into one.

Second, re-reading your question: having duplicate element id attributes is **NOT VALID HTML**.  If you want to get everything in one go with a [specificity one selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), then do `<input ... class="form__input" />` and use this as your jQuery selector `var $inputs = $(".form__input");`

Object.assign will merge two objects and will work in most browsers (MSIE needs a shim)

```
var a = { a: 1 }, b = { b: 2 }, c;

c = Object.assign( {}, a, b );

console.log( JSON.stringify( c ) );

// { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```