# How to add to a multi object literal in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Data sample taken from JQVmap:

```
var jvmCountries = {
  "AF": {"name": "Afghanistan", "coords": [33, 65]},
  "AL": {"name": "Albania", "coords": [41, 20]},
  "DZ": {"name": "Algeria", "coords": [28, 3]},
  "AO": {"name": "Angola", "coords": [-12.5, 18.5]},
  "AR": {"name": "Argentina", "coords": [-34, -64]},
  "AM": {"name": "Armenia", "coords": [40, 45]}
}
```

How can I add a new country to this? I believe you can add to an object literal using `Object.assign()`, but I'm not sure how to do so with those country abbreviation keys and each country having multiple values (a name and coords).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: What do you mean by "*Each country having multiple values*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) helpful in this case, but adding properties (in your case a country containing an object) can be done like this:

```
jvmCountries['AA'] = {
  name: 'A New Country',
  coords: [500, 404]
};
```