# Invalid assignment left-hand side ( working with emailTemp Files )

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to add data to my EmailTemplate in the for loop. 
Unfortunately this does not work as expected. I get the error code "Invalid assignment left-hand side." every time.
I want the counter to go up after each run and adapt to the temp file.

Here is the "problem Code". Without it the Script runs perfectly.

```
var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("template"); // Access to the HTML document       
var z = 1;
    var softindexlen = softwareindex.length;
    for(var b = 0; b<softindexlen; b++){
      if (b<6){
        emailTemp.PCCI+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][0]];
        emailTemp.PCEquip+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][7]];
        emailTemp.PCassetname+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][1]];
        emailTemp.PCassettag+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][4]];
        emailTemp.PCserial+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][9]];
        emailTemp.PCmanufac+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][5]];
        emailTemp.PCmodel+z = computerarray[softwareindex[b][6]];
        z++;
      }else{
        emailTemp.pcnotification = pcnotification;
        break;

      }
    }
```

Hopefully someone of you can help me ! (And sorry if the header isn't the best )

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) said, you have to use the bracket notation to access properties (what you access with `a.b`) with dynamic names.

To do this, you can use the nature of Apps Script to access the properties by name with `[name]`.

Since your names include a dynamic number, try accessing the properties like this:

```
emailTemp["PCCI"+z] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation:

```
emailTemp["PCCI"+z] = /*some value*/
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error-message "Missing name after . operator. "

Comment: PCCI needs to be string-quoted