# QML defining an object property

Tags: qt, properties, qml

I am trying to create a map in QML, the only way I've found to do this is:

```
    readonly property variant translate: { "Hello" : "123" }
```

Then in the QML I can get 123 by using:

```
    idOfItem.translate["Hello"]
```

This works fine and when doing this I get "123" returned as desired.  Now what I want to do is define another property to replace "Hello" which can be used in the QML, ideally something like:

```
    readonly property string strHello: "Hello"
    readonly property variant translate: { strHello : "123" }
```

Then in the QML:

```
    idOfItem.translate[idOfItem.strHello]
```

This doesn't work and when trying to put strHello into the initial definition a read underscore appears under ":".

Can this be resolved?

Comment: you've define an object that has property named `strHello` and its value is `123`. The object has no property named `Hello`. you should use `[]`, not `{}` if you want to define array, not object. But I strongly advise you to get some JavaScript tutorial first to learn it.

Comment: @folibis, I'm very fluent in JavaScript, the property strHello contains the key "Hello" which does exist in the object and its this I want to use to lookup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a JavaScript question/issue.

You *can* create an object with dynamic property names, but *not* at declaration/initialization time. You have to do it dynamically, eg.:

```
readonly property string strHello: "Hello"
property var translate: ({})

function populate() {
  translate[strHello] = "123";

  console.log(translate[strHello]);
}

Component.onCompleted: populate();
```

See the following question, for example, but note that QtQuick doesn't support ES6.
[Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: I understand how it can be done in JavaScript, I couldn't find an equivalent constructor in QML, there is onCompleted as you have posted, is this the correct place to initialise properties?

Comment: Well depends on your code/style/etc, but yes, that's a pretty typical place to init things within Components. Really depends on where/how your `translate` object exists in relation to what uses it, etc.  BTW if this is literally for translation purposes then hopefully you already know about [qsTr()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html) and such (which can be used for other text abstraction besides internationalization).

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate.