# variable derived js object property

Tags: qml

I need to add properties to a JS object in QML. I don't know the properties in advance. So I am stuck.

I found this topic with same issue: [QML defining an object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971166/qml-defining-an-object-property)

The only way to solve this coming up in my mind is to create a QMap on C++ side and to pass it back to QML.

Any other suggestions using JS?

```
Repeater{
    model:3
    delegate:
        TextInput{
        text:"zfs"
        Component.onCompleted: {
            var prop="name"
            var obj=({prop:text})
            //results in {prop:"zfs"} but I need {name:"zfs"}
            // maybe c++ function: QMap createJSObject(prop,text)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array-like syntax, like this:

```
var prop="name"
var obj = {};
obj[prop] = text;
```

That should give you the output `{name: "zfs"}`