# Why does state behave in such a way while Updating state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have my state like

```
this.state = {
      data: [],
      dataloaded: false,
      isopen: false,
      firstname: '',
      lastname:'',
      email:'',
      gender: '',
      avatar: '',
      number:'',
      dob:new Date()
    };
```

And I am having form to update state,

every text input has onchange such as this `onChange={this.handleOnChange("firstname")}`

And my hndleOnChange function is:

```
handleOnChange = field => event => {
    console.log(event.target.value,field)
    this.setState({field: event.target.value})
  }
```

**this doesnt work**
This is not updating the state
but if i do

```
handleOnChange = field => event => {
    console.log(event.target.value,field)
    this.setState({[field]: event.target.value})
  }
```

**this works**

Why does adding bracket infront of objectname it gets correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding brackets means the `value` of that variable becomes the object key. Without brackets, the literal name becomes the object key. As an example:

```
const key = "name";

const object = {
    key: "My Key",
    name: "My Name"
};

obj.key // "My Key"
obj[key] // "My Name" -> equivalent to obj["name"] or object.name
```

Check out MDN's [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more information.

In you case, this code:

```
handleOnChange = field => event => {
    console.log(event.target.value,field)
    this.setState({field: event.target.value})
}
```

is trying to set a state property named `field`, instead of the state property associated with the value of the field variable.