# How to push an object into another nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to push a row to my array. I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = [
    [
        { "id": 1, "name": "John" },
        // Another object
    ],
    [
        { "id": 1, "name": "Jeff" },
        { "id": 2, "name": "Jane" },
    ]
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: @Tân this can't help me, I want to add another JSON inside double JSON array.

Comment: I've given you the way to *add* it. Please read the answer carefully.

Comment: @Tân It seems Shardad needs  PHP solution, not that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json= '
    [
        [
            {
                "text":"Row 1 Column 1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text":"Row 2 Column 1"
            },
            {
                "text":"Row 2 Column 2"
            }
        ]
    ]
    ';

    $p = json_decode($j);

    $p[0][]=["text"=>"Row 1 Column 2"];

    print_r(json_encode($p)); // print_r for debug, $result = json_encode($p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first handle your data in a array and then convert it to a json array

I would do it like this :

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            "text" => "Row 1 Column 1"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "text" => "Row 2 Column 1"
        ],
        [
            "text" => "Row 2 Column 2"
        ]
    ]
];

// a element in the first sub array
$array[0][] = [
    "text" => "Row 1 Column 2"
];
```

Does that help ?