# NodeJS: How to add a variable to the return for a JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I am very new to node.js.

I have a JSON that I am reading from a website.  Without posting too much of the JSON, here's roughly what I'm looking at:

```
{
   "Head": {
      "Front": "80",
      "Side": "85",
      "Back": "75"
   },
   "Neck": {
      "Front": "65",
      "Side": "70",
      "Back": "60"
   }
}
```

I have a function that is formatted the following way:

```
function whichBodyPart(part, file, time) {
      var fileParse = JSON.parse(file);
      var type;
      switch(time.toLowerCase()){
        case ('9AM'):
            type = 'Front';
        break;
        case ('12PM'):
            type = 'Side';
        break;
        case ('3PM'):
            type = 'Back';
        break;
    }
    return fileParse.part.type;
  }
```

**part** is a user-passed-in value that, in this case, would either be "Head" or "Neck"

**file** is the un-parsed JSON file.  I parse it in the function.

I know that to pull a specific element's value out of the JSON file I have here, I could do something along the lines of

**return fileParse**.***Head.Back***

and that would give me back the value "75".  However, what I'm trying to do is navigate the JSON with the values from the variables **part** and **type**.

For example, if **part** is "Neck" and **type** is "Side", I want to retrieve the value "70" from the JSON.  However, if the user input **part** as "Head" and **type** is "Front", I want to receive "80".

How do I make the return able to handle varying inputs?

Comment: use the bracket notation `fileParse[part][type]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object) and [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Thank you guys.  I was unaware of this notation and for some reason couldn't find it specifically.  I figured something had to exist to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use bracket notation of JavaScript to handle your varying inputs. Try:

```js
return fileParse[part][type]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not sure why I couldn't find this syntax.  Probably wasn't wording it correctly on Google.  But I got it working :)