# How to apply map operation on array to add properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to add the property `type` as `billing` to the result of a mongodb operation. I treid many answers from [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object), like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512466/6655884 here:

```js
    let r1 = await Billing.find({
      launchDate: {
        "$gte": new Date(req.query.minDate),
        "$lte": new Date(req.query.maxDate)
      },
      deleted: false,
      status: "pago"
    });

    r1.map((obj)=>({...obj,['type']:"billing"}));
```

But when I print `r1`, there's no `type` property.

**UPDATE:**

What about

```
for (var i=0; i<r1.length; i++) {
    r1[i]['type'] = "billing";
}
```

?

It doesn't work either

Comment: Presuming *r1* is an array like `[{launchDate: {...}, deleted: false, status:'pago}]`, then the code "works" and does add a *type* property. But it's added to the array *returned* by `r1.map(...)`, the *r1* array itself isn't modified.

Comment: You can use an aggregation query to add a new field to the query result. The [aggregation stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) `$project` and `addFields` can be used for this. You can add this stage after your initial `$match` stage with the query filter.

Comment: @RobG I added and I don't know if it works. When I print now I get `[Object object ...]`. I also tried a new simpler way, can you look at my update? It also won't work. I see no changes in `r1`

Comment: What does the print output from the variable `r1` look like immediately _after_ the `find`?

Comment: [JavaScript's map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function works on an array. So use the [cursor's toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html#toArray) on the `find` _and_ then apply the `map`.

Comment: In regard to "what about…" you can do `r1.forEach(item => item.type = 'billing')`. There's not much point in `['type']` for the property name, it's the same as `'type'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could possible be happening because of mongoose `.find()` might be resulting in raw MongoDB docs rather than javascript objects, try to use `.lean()` to convert result into Js object in order to manipulate it :

```
 let r1 = await Billing.find({
      launchDate: {
        "$gte": new Date(req.query.minDate),
        "$lte": new Date(req.query.maxDate)
      },
      deleted: false,
      status: "pago"
    }).lean();

    r1.map((obj)=>({...obj,['type']:"billing"}));
```

Or alternatively you can do it in query using [aggregation-pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) :

```
 let r1 = await Billing.aggregate([
  /** Filter docs with criteria */
  {
    $match: { }
  },
  /** Add new field to all returned docs */
  {
    $addFields: {
      type: "Billing"
    }
  }
]);
```