# Difference between object.key and object[key] in for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

Why after I replaced `if (typeof obj[key] == 'object')` with `if (typeof obj.key == 'object')` the result is not expect.
this is my code:

```
var animals = {
  bird: {
    color: 'blue',
    action: {
      fly: true,
      nesting: true,
      swim:false
    },
    eat:'insect'
  }
};
function GetObjectKeys(obj, keys) {
 for (let key in obj) {
     //if (typeof obj.key == 'object')
       if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') 
  {
           keys.push(key);
           GetObjectKeys(obj[key], keys);
       } 
else {
           keys.push(key);
       }
   }
   return keys;
}
arrKeys = [];
GetObjectKeys(animals, arrKeys); 

//
- result expect:
[
  'bird',    'color',
  'action',  'fly',
  'nesting', 'swim',
  'eat'
]
- result when use if (typeof obj.key == 'object') :
[ 'bird' ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll need to paste in here the results you see and then the results that you _expect_ to see. This will help us determine what you are trying to do.

Comment: When you use `obj.keys` it looks for a property named literally **"key"** INSIDE the object. BUT there is none with that name! More info: [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

The **key** on your **dot notation** example(`obj.key`) is a string, your obj doesn't have the property named **key**, hence it's undefined.

You are passing in a variable in your bracket notation, `for (let key in obj)` loops all the property names in your object **obj**. so **obj[key]** basically equals to **obj['bird']** from your first function call.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

The way I see it, When you use `for...in` expression, `key` is being the key with string type. like `"key1"`,`"key2"`,`"key3'`

so, when you use `key` like `obj.key` it is like `obj."key`. So it occur some error.

so you can use dynamic property keys like `obj[key]`.

### Reference

- https://usefulangle.com/post/196/javascript-object-dynamic-key

Answer (score 1):

- `obj.key` equal `obj["key"]` will look for `"key"` as a property in your object, and obviously there is no `key` property in `animals` object ==> `obj.key` equal `obj["key"]` is `undefined`. ==> you got unexpected result.
- `obj[key]` is dynamically take the value of `key` to pass in the notation. E.g `const key = "name"` => `obj[key]` equal `obj.name`. It is `"bird"` in your case `obj[key]` equal `obj["bird"]` equal `obj.bird`

Answer (score 0):

using obj[key] is better for this type of use. Look here:

```
var obj = {key: 1, key2: 2}
var key = 'key2';

obj.key = 3;
obj[key] = 4; // result: {key: 3, key2: 4}
```