# How to get the value of iterating object? Without using foreach and dot operator

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var myObject = {
 name : 'David',
 age: '30,
 salary:'30000'
}
```

I need answers like:
My name is **David**, I'm **30** years old. I earned monthly **30000**.

Note: Without using '.' DOT operator and for and foreach.

Comment: Does `Object.entries(...).map` count as an iteration to you?

Comment: I think it's an iteration

Comment: What is the iteration here supposed to be?

Comment: Nice tricky question, I learned new thinks thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var myObject = {
name : 'David',
age: '30',
salary:'30000'
}
//object destructure

let {name, age, salary} = myObject;

console.log(`my name is ${name}`)

Answer (score 3):

**This should work:**

```
var myObject = {
    'name' : 'David',
    'age': '30',
    'salary':'30000'
 };
console.log('My name is '+myObject['name']);
```

**Here is the JSFiddle Example:**
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Karthikeyan_N/rtcngq8y/)

Comment: `['key']` would be equivalent to `.key` so I don't know how this bypasses the "no dot" requirement of OP. Something is a bit off here

Comment: object.key and object[key] accomplish the same thing. However, object.key only works if the key name is hardwired ( I mean not happening dynamically since it cannot change at run-time). It also does not work when the key is a number instead of a string.

In other words, object[key] is more versatile.
https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/54c30d4195e378bd8900045b#:~:text=key%20and%20object%5Bkey%5D%20accomplish,number%20instead%20of%20a%20string.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481352/difference-between-object-key-and-objectkey-in-for-loop-in-javascript](Difference)

Comment: Yes I am aware of that however **here** in this particular case the key **is** hardwired making this syntax less readable.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myObject = {
    'name' : 'David',
    'age': '30',
    'salary':'30000'
 };
console.log(`My name is ${myObject["name"]}, I'm ${myObject["age"]} years old. I earned monthly ${myObject['salary']}.`);
```

Comment: This doesn't work: Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined