# Unable to edit JavaScript object with dynamically named properties: property is missing in object literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand why this code would not work:

```js
 const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    var data = {
      some_var: 0,
    };
    data["test"] = "test";
    return data;
  });
```

I get the following error:
*Cannot assign `"test"` to `data["test"]` because property `test` is missing in  object literal*

but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object) post this is something I should be able to validly do in JS.

Comment: are you import `import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";`

Comment: try making putting ```some_var``` in quotes like ```'some_var'```. and also use ```let data = {``` i suspect the hoisting is making it act strange.

Comment: var data = {    "some_var": 0,   };

Comment: @noor yes, I am

Comment: @berlin thanks, still getting the same error message though :/

Comment: @zahrazamani still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error? Sounds like a typescript compilation thing.

Comment: I've tried your example code and it is working fine. I can access test property and can update the state as well. Please refer to this: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dust-rsm16

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => {
    var data = {
      some_var: 0,
    };
    data["test"] = "test";
    return data;
  
  });
  console.log(data)====>{some_var: 0, test: "test"}

  return (
    <div >
     
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```