# Change Object Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there way to change the index dynamically? or rebuild this object to where the 1 will be the Id of what ever object get passed into the function? Hope this makes sense.

```
export const createTree = (parentObj) => {

//keep in memory reference for later
const flatlist = { 1: parentObj }; <---- change the 1 based on parent.Id

...

}
```

My attempt thinking it would be easy as:

```
const flatlist = { parentObj.Id: parentObj };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to create a key from an expression:

```js
const createTree = (parentObj) => {
  const flatlist = { [parentObj.id]: parentObj };

  return flatlist;
}

console.log(createTree({ id: 1 }));
```