# Javascript object declaration with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm declaring an object inside one of my components like below:

```
const data = {
        user: id,
        userRole: role,
        teacherdepartment: department
}
```

But now I wanted to do this declaration dynamically depends on a specific value, like below:

```
let usertype='teacher';
const data = {
        user: id,
        userRole: role,
        if(usertype=='teacher'?(teacherdepartment:tdepartment):(studentDepartment:sdepartment))
}
```

Is this possible. I know I can do it with nested ternary operator. But inside the object structure any simple line that can do that trick?

Update: object values can be easily set using ternary inside the object declaration, but this is for object key so this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object). Also, in the above example I have put a simple object. Image if the objects have some child and ternary conditions within.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid a ternary operator altogether because they're confusing to read in a lot of situations. Instead I would create a dictionary that maps user types to string values, and then create the property dynamically with that information.

```js
const userType = 'teacher';

const dict = { teacher: 'tdepartment', student: 'sdepartment' };

const data = {
  user: 'id',
  userRole: 'role',
  [`${userType}Department`]: dict[userType]
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with conditional operator for both key and value. Keys can be made dynamic by adding `[]` around the key expression.

**Pseude Code**

```
const data = {
    user: id,
    userRole: role,
    [usertype=='teacher'? 'teacherdepartment' : 'studentDepartment']: usertype=='teacher'? tdepartment: sdepartment,
}
```

**Working Code**

```js
const usertype = 'student';
const tdepartment = 'tdepartment';
const sdepartment = 'sdepartment';
const id = 'id';
const role = 'role';
const data = {
  user: id,
  userRole: role,
  [usertype=='teacher'? 'teacherdepartment' : 'studentDepartment']: usertype=='teacher'? tdepartment: sdepartment,
};
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be refactored into

```js
let usertype = 'teacher';

let departmentProperty = usertype === 'teacher' ? 'teacherdepartment' : 'studentDepartment';
let departmentValue = usertype === 'teacher' ? 'teacherdepartmentValue' : 'studentDepartment';
const data = {
    user: 'id',
    userRole: 'role',
    [departmentProperty]: departmentValue,
};

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this *can* be done in a "one-liner" IMO to preserve readability it *shouldn't* be.

Instead, check `usertype` and create an object to include in the resulting `data` object. This way the changes based on `usertype` are isolated and easy to reason about. It also allows for additional changes based on `usertype` as it's isolated from the static properties.

```
const deptInfo = usertype === 'teacher' ? { teacherDepartment: tDepartment }
  : { studentDepartment: sDepartment }

const data = {
  ...deptInfo,
  user: id,
  userRole: role,
}
```