# How do I name an imported module dynamically with javascript eval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, eval

I want to create a dynamically named variable so that I can use it as a module. I am using eval() to do it, but for some reason it's not working as expected and claiming that the constant I created inside of it doesn't exist.

I have a main folder with this structure:

```
main
|- commands
|- |- testmod.js
|- test.js
```

Testmod.js has a simple function export inside of it that logs something to console when run:

```
function cmd() {
    console.log('it worked :)');
}

module.exports = { cmd };
```

And in test.js, I want to try importing it dynamically:

```
const foo = 'testmodule';
eval(`const ${foo} = require('./commands/testmod.js');`);

eval(`${foo}.cmd();`)
```

However, it runs with an error, `ReferenceError: testmodule is not defined`, and I don't know why.
Expected:

```
1. define a variable named foo
2. evaluate a string that requires contents of another js file, and name that import as the contents of variable foo
3. evaluate this: a module with name of variable foo and then run the command 'cmd()' inside of it.

expected output: it worked :)
```

Should I try to find a different method of dynamically naming variables? I'm 99% sure that this method of doing things is unstable and unintended, but if I could get it to work somehow it would be great.

Comment: `const` is scoped to the block in which it is defined. That means that the `testmodule` constant is not available outside of the scope of `eval`. However, using `eval` should be avoided if possible. You can dynamically create properties on objects: `const bar[foo] = require('./commands/testmod.js');` [See this related question](/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Do you have any links to questions that have more explanation on how to do the `bar[foo]` thing? I don't really understand how to implement it.
edit: nevermind, I think i've got something working now. [This question makes it more understandable for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so my solution was to create an Object, then assign stuff to it. This way, there aren't any new variables and its just an object that can be called later. Thanks Emiel.

```
const foo = 'testmodule';
let bar = {
    foo: require('./commands/testmod.js'),
};

bar.foo.cmd();
```