# How to replace object key name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a response from an API call and I would like to change the name of the output. Here is the object:

```
{
  "sales": 312,
  "city": "Berlin",
}
```

My desired output is:

```
{
  "value": 312,
  "name": "Berlin",
}
```

I tried this code:

```
const dicts = data
const array = []
for (let dict in dicts) {
    const dictionary = dict
    Object.assign(dictionary, { name: dictionary.oldKey })['city']
    Object.assign(dictionary, { value: dictionary.oldKey })['sales']
    delete dictionary['city'];
    delete dictionary['sales'];
    array.push(dictionary);
}
return array
```

But I got an empty array as a result.

Could you please help me with this? I am new to Javascript and will use this code in Budibase to create an app.

Comment: `obj.name = obj.city; delete obj.city`

Comment: what is `dictionary.oldKey`

Comment: `data.map(({sales, city}) => ({value: sales, name: city}))`

Comment: @HassanImam, objects have no `.map` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Object Rename Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key)

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this by creating a new object with the desired property

```js
// Original object from the API
const original = {
  "sales": 312,
  "city": "Berlin"
};

// Create a new object with the desired property names
const desired = {
"value": original["sales"],
"name": original["city"]
};

console.log(desired);
```

Comment: The question is about modifying the object in-place. This answer creates a new object and doesn't modify the original.

Comment: this is a example how to make !, not a ready code original to var and rewrite json make one object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you're trying to mutate the objects in place? A more typical approach would be somehting like this.

```js
return data.map(item => {
  return {
    value: item.sales,
    name: item.city,
  }
}
```

See [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for reference.

Comment: object's have no `.map` method - you're seeing an Array as input where there is none :p

Comment: @JaromandaX they seem to be working with a list of object, judging by the `for` cycle, `ditcs` and therefore `data` is likely an array